# In knockoutjs are objects clones or do they reference the same thing?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, clone, knockout-2.0

I built an app in early version of knockout and the code looked like:

```
    var ProductCollection = function(products, metadata) {
        var self = this;
        this.allProducts = products;
        this.activeProducts = ko.observableArray(products);
```

Then if I filtered out items from the activeProduct array like:

```
    this.activeProducts.remove(function(item) { //some code })
```

I was able to reset activeProducts to all products by doing something like:

```
    this.activeProducts(this.allProducts);
```

But now it seems like if I do the remove function above its removing products from this.allProducts also...  Is the products i'm passing in and setting linking to the same reference or something? I don't get why this would happen now and not before. I'd like to be able to keep this.activeProducts and this.allProducts as separate arrays.

Comment: `products` is the same array in both cases.  You will want `activeProducts` to either be a copy of the array (`products.slice(0)` is a quick way to do that) or you can use a `computed` observable to represent the filtered version of your products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your experimentation has shown, `ko.observableArray()` simply wraps the underlying array. It **doesn't** clone the underlying array and then make a new instance.

Here's more from the the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

> An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array...
>
> An observableArray just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed...
>
> ...You can get the underlying JavaScript array by invoking the observableArray as a function with no parameters...
>
> Technically you can use any of the native JavaScript array functions to operate on that underlying array...

---

```
// Thanks @RP Niemeyer
this.activeProducts = ko.observableArray(products.slice(0));

// Deep copy with jQuery
this.activeProducts = ko.observableArray(jQuery.extend(true, {}, products));
```

Also, if you're really curious, there's an entire question dedicated to Javascript cloning [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/109941).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you happen to know if older versions Knockout actually cloned the data for you? It use to work as if I had done the cloning without having to clone it as you have shown above.

Comment: @michael: Hmm... I doubt it. Knockout aims to be a lightweight JavaScript library, and I doubt that the library would clone arrays on your behalf if the documentation didn't explicitly say that it would.